# How to convert column heading to column values and its values in another column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose, unpivot

I have a table like this say the table name is online-websites and the values it has is the number of times I used it.

| Amazon | Flipkart | Myntra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 3 |

I want to convert it to following format

| Website name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | 5 |
| Flipkart | 4 |
| Myntra | 3. |

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your specific example one common way to unpivot is to lateral-join to a values-table construct:

```
select p.*
from t,
lateral (
  values
  ('Amazon', t.Amazon),
  ('Flipkart', t.Flipkart),
  ('Myntra', t.Myntra)
)p(SiteName, count)
order by count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bizarre case that you do not know the number of columns beforehand, you can use `jsonb` functions to pivot unknown columns to rows.

```
select e.*
  from online_websites
       cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(
                            to_jsonb(online_websites)
                          ) as e(website_name, "count");
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3ff342954736d84a776ff0918cd25d51)*

Comment: Thanks @Mike Organek. Both the answers worked, however I am able to accept only one answer.

Comment: @Praneetha  That is quite all right.  I said in this answer that this would be for a "bizarre case". :-)